# Upload file to SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, development, file-upload

**Error message:**

> The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.'

**Code:**

```
namespace SharepointUpload
{
    public partial class SharepointUpload : System.Windows.Forms.Form
    {
        public SharepointUpload()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        string path = "";
        string file = "";
        string fileName = "";

        private void pathBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            System.Net.WebRequest request = System.Net.HttpWebRequest.Create("http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap//_vti_bin/Copy.asmx");

            request.UseDefaultCredentials = true;

            request.PreAuthenticate = true;

            request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;

            System.Net.WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();

            openFileDialog1.FileName = String.Empty;
            if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
            {
                path = openFileDialog1.FileName;
                file = Path.GetFileName(openFileDialog1.FileName);
                fileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(openFileDialog1.FileName);
                //path = fileName;
                pathTxt.Text = path;
            }
        }

        private void uploadBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            System.Net.NetworkCredential credential = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(userTxt.Text, passTxt.Text, domainTxt.Text);
            //ClientContext client = new ClientContexthttps://sharepoint.domain.lan/path/to/service/") 
            ClientContext client = new ClientContext("http://sever/sites/Folder");
            client.RequestTimeout = 3600000;
            client.ExecutingWebRequest += new EventHandler<WebRequestEventArgs>(client_ExecutingWebRequtest);
            client.Credentials = credential;
            MemoryStream stream;
            using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(pathTxt.Text, FileMode.Open))
            {
                byte[] buffer = new byte[16 * 1024];
                byte[] byteArr;

                using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    int read;
                    while ((read = fs.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
                    {
                        ms.Write(buffer, 0, read);
                    }
                    byteArr = ms.ToArray();
                }

                stream = new MemoryStream(byteArr);

                var fi = new FileInfo(pathTxt.Text);
                //Project Administration presents root folder
                var list = client.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Test");
                client.Load(list.RootFolder);
                client.ExecuteQuery();
                var fileUrl = list.RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl + "/"+folderTxt.Text+"/" + fi.Name;
                client.RequestTimeout = Timeout.Infinite;
                try
                {
                    Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File.SaveBinaryDirect(client, fileUrl, stream, true);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Something went wrong: "+ex.ToString(), "Error...!", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
                    return;
                }
            }
            MessageBox.Show("Upload has completed...", "Information...", MessageBoxButtons.OK);

        }

        //this event is to prevent form based authentication. It uses windows instead.
        static void client_ExecutingWebRequtest(object sender, WebRequestEventArgs e)
        {
            e.WebRequestExecutor.WebRequest.Headers.Add("X-FORMS_BASED_AUTH_ACCEPTED", "f");
        }
```

I would be most grateful for any assistance as I have tried solving this for weeks using different methods.

Answer (score 1):

You must use [SharePointOnlineCredentials](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-server/jj164693(v%3Doffice.15)) instead of the NetworkCredential. Here is a sample:

```
using (ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext("https://contoso.sharepoint.com/"))  
{  
    SecureString password = new SecureString();
    clientContext.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials("loginname@yoursite.onmicrosoft.com", password);
    Web web = clientContext.Web;
    clientContext.Load(web);
    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
    Console.WriteLine(web.Title);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Download SharePoint Online csom library and use SharePointOnlineCredentials class to pass credential, here is a code demo to upload file to Documents RootFolder:

```
 using (ClientContext cnx = new ClientContext("https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/dev"))
            {
                string password = "********";
                string account = "user@tenant.onmicrosoft.com";
                var secret = new SecureString();
                foreach (char c in password)
                {
                    secret.AppendChar(c);
                }
                cnx.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(account, secret);

                Web web = cnx.Web;

                FileCreationInformation newFile = new FileCreationInformation();
                newFile.Content = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes("c:\\test.jpg");

                //file url is name
                newFile.Url = @"test.jpg";
                List docs = web.Lists.GetByTitle("Documents");

                //get folder and add to that
                Folder folder = docs.RootFolder;
                File uploadFile = folder.Files.Add(newFile);

                cnx.Load(docs);
                cnx.Load(uploadFile);
                cnx.ExecuteQuery();
                Console.WriteLine("done");
            };
```